# Wordpress rewrite rules, endpoints and showing appropriate template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been given a task that requires me to create a new endpoint/permalink.

Something like `www.myswebsite.com/users` where a list of users will be shown. Then `www.mywebsite.com/users/1` will show the information of user 1.

THAT part if done. I have the url set, visiting the url serves the appropriate template to the user. The individual information is shown as intended.

However... I am making a mistake because the `users.php` template is being shown for ALL other urls. So the base url `www.mywebsite.com` is also showing `www.mywebsite.com/users` template. How can I fix this?

Below is the code in my plugin. Should you need more information from me, please don't hesitate to ask.

I know my problem is at the `get_new_template` function but I am not well versed in Wordpress to determine the correct `if/else` block.

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: User Endpoint
* Description: Providing An Endpoint For Data Consumption
* Version: 1.0.0
*/

// Add a new var to query vars
function result_add_query_vars( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'users';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'result_add_query_vars' );

// Register ReWrite-Rules
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'users', EP_ROOT );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^users/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&param=foo',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);

// Register Template To Show At End POint
function get_new_template( $original_template ) {
  if ( get_query_var('users/') ) {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/user.php';
    }   else {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/users.php';
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'get_new_template' );

// Flush Permalinks
function flush_permalinks() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'flush_permalinks');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling WP to use the same template for all here and your did not return the original template for other pages that do match your case.  See code below for fix:

```
// Register Template To Show At End Point
function get_new_template($original_template)
{
    global $wp_query;

    // /users or /users/xxxx
    if (isset($wp_query->query['users'])) {
        // "user id"
        $page = $wp_query->query['users'];

        $template = $page >= 1 ? '/user.php' : '/users.php';

        return dirname(__FILE__) .  $template;
    }

    return $original_template;
}
add_filter('template_include', 'get_new_template');
```

Comment: Issue is I have 2 templates. One named `user.php` and another named `users.php`. 
That is not included in the above if block.

Comment: OK, So what is case for each template to be shown so I can update the answer?

Comment: So when the user visits `www.mywebsite.com/users/` the template `users.php` is shown.

When the user visits `www.mywebsite.com/users/1` the template `user.php` is shown.

Comment: Please feel free to question my entire logic. I suspect I may have done a # of items wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer.  This is working on my local machine running the latest WP.

Comment: Just tried it. Does not work on my end. Neither of the templates show. 

Do you think it has anything to do with the permalink settings (mine is current in 'Post Name')?

Comment: Can I share the plugin code with you? It is in a BitBucket repo

Comment: Sure.  I can take a look.  I updated my answer to use `global $wp_query`.  this might work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210818/discussion-between-mikerojas-and-riza-khan).